# Can copy() cannot be use for initializing a container?

Tags: c++, list, stl, copy

Can copy() be used for initializing a container? The following code has a runtime error: "list iterator not dereferencable". What would be the reason for this? Thanks

```
string  a[] = {"00", "11", "22"};
list<string> list_1(a, a+3), list_2;
copy(list_1.begin(), list_1.end(), list_2.begin()); // error:
```

Comment: You should go back to your old questions and accept some answers.

Comment: "initializing" has a specific meaning in C++. It's a one-time process, done as part of object definition. Here, for instance, `list_2` is initialized as the empty vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list_2` has no space where to copy the source range. You have to either reserve enough space, or use an inserter iterator. Alternatively, you could just use the `list` constructor:

```
std::list< std::string > list_2( list_1.begin(), list_1.end() );
```

or further on the `assign` member function:

```
list_2.assign( list_1.begin(), list_1.end() );
```

Comment: might as well mention `insert(It1, It2, It2)` :) +1

Answer (score 2):

```
string  a[] = {"00", "11", "22"};
list<string> list_1(a, a+3);
```

Many options:

```
// #include <iterator>

list<string> list_2;
copy(list_1.begin(), list_1.end(), std::back_inserter(list_2));
```

or

```
list<string> list_2(list_1.begin(), list_1.end()); // range ctor
```

or

```
list<string> list_2(list_1); // copy ctor
```

or even:

```
list<string> list_2;
list_2.assign(list_1.begin(), list_1.end()); // range assignment
```

or:

```
list_2.insert(list_2.end(), list_1.begin(), list_1.end()); // range insert
```

or:

```
vector<string> vec(list_1.size()); // pre-allocating ctor
copy(list_1.begin(), list_1.end(), vec.begin());
```

or:

```
vector<string> vec;
// ....
vec.clear();
vec.resize(list_1.size()); // pre-allocate existing vector

copy(list_1.begin(), list_1.end(), vec.begin());
```

The possibilities are... endless

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`back_insert_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_insert_iterator/), to be got from [`std::back_inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/), rather than the iterator from `list_2.begin`. The latter doesn't allocate memory for the items that `copy` is trying to insert.